# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this code snippet result in: `TypeError 'int' object is not subscriptable`?

```
return (bin(int(hexdata)[2:].zfill(16)))
```

`hexdata` is a hexadecimal string. For example, it may be `0x0101`.

Comment: your are applying [] to int(hexdata) which is integer

Comment: so you're suggesting bin(int(hexdata[2:])).zfill(16))?

Comment: if that's your intent, then yes.  bin returns a string which i assume you want to pad?  however, if i understand correctly, hexdata is a hexidecimal string? in that case you need to specify correct base, eg `int("0xA", 16)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
>>> int('1234')[2:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

>>> 1234[2:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If you intended to remove the first two character, use following:

```
>>> int('1234'[2:])
34
```

If the orignal string is hexadecimal representation, you should pass optional `base` argument 16

```
>>> int('1234'[2:], 16)
52
```

If `[2:]` is used to remove `0b` generated by `bin` (not to remove leading characters from the original string), then following is what you want.

```
>>> int('0x1234', 16) # No need to remove leading `0x`
4660
>>> int('0x1234', 0)  # automatically recognize the number's base using the prefix
4660
>>> int('1234', 16)
4660
>>> bin(int('1234', 16))
'0b1001000110100'
>>> bin(int('1234', 16))[2:]
'1001000110100'
>>> bin(int('1234', 16))[2:].zfill(16)
'0001001000110100'
```

BTW, you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) instead of `bin` + `str.zfill`:

```
>>> '{:016b}'.format(int('1234', 16))
'0001001000110100'
>>> format(int('1234', 16), '016b')
'0001001000110100'
```

**UPDATE**

If you specify 0 as a base, `int` will automatically recognize the number's base using the prefix.

```
>>> int('0x10', 0)
16
>>> int('10', 0)
10
>>> int('010', 0)
8
>>> int('0b10', 0)
2
```

Comment: The 2-subscript is clearly to get rid of the `0x` from the sample number `0x0101`. I think all the stuff about `"1234"[2:]` is probably superfluous.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I don't think so. Try `int('0x12')`: raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x12'`, which is different from what OP mentioned int he question.

Comment: @paxdiablo, IMHO, `[2:]` was used to remove `0b` prepended by `bin`.

Comment: Actually, you're right, `int(x,16)` happily accept numbers of the form `0xWhatever`. But I still think that the bits suggesting `int('1234'[2:])` are not necessary in the answer, since they're not touching a `0bxxxx` string.

Comment: @paxdiablo, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that using base 0 will automatically recognize the number's base using the prefix. `int('0x10', 0) == 16`, `int('10', 0) == 10`, `int('010', 0) == 8`, `int('0b10', 0) == 2`.

Comment: @swenzel, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses in the wrong place. Assuming you have a string like "0x0101" where you want to end up with a 16-digit binary string:

```
bin(int(hexdata,16))[2:].zfill(16)
```

The `int(X,16)` call interprets that as a hex number (and can accept a number of the form `0xSomething`). Then `bin(X)` turns that into a string of the form `0b01010101`.

The `[2:]` then gets rid of the `0b` at the front and `zfill(16)` fills that out to 16 "bits".

```
>>> bin(int("0x0102",16))[2:].zfill(16)
'0000000100000010'
```

Comment: should set the base to 16: `int(hexdata, 16)`

Comment: It's hex: "hexdata is a hexadecimal string. for example, it may be 0x0101"